# how to edit windows 10 iso to exclude other versions

Tags: windows-10, boot, iso-image, windows-installation, wim

I have been going through the process of slimming down my windows 10 ISO file, but have been unable to get it below the 3.5 gb mark; Removing the windows components is not something I am hoping to do. However, I found that a majority of the install.esd file can be removed if you only keep the windows 10 pro (index 6) files and exclude everything else. Unfortunately, the furthest I have gotten is creating a .wim file that only contains the windows 10 pro installation, but am unsure as how to turn this wim file into a full iso installation of windows. Perhaps converting it to a wim was wrong? Or maybe there is a way to turn the wim file into a fully fledged iso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows code for various versions shares numerous common elements. So if you try to remove versions you do not want, you do not get a decrease that matches the version removed. Also, the installer picks up other features and drivers at the time of installation.

Here is a decently good explanation of the construction of the Windows 10 ISO.

[Windows 10 ISO construction](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/f8ec140a-0a44-48d0-911e-d4d3eb6d72ca/windows-iso-customization-delete-unwanted-windows-editions-to-reduce-iso-size?forum=mdt)

> No, you are assuming that the WIndows Server install.wim file contains
> 4 *SEPERATE* Operating Systems, and thay by removing the other 3, you
> will get a proportional decrease in size, that is a incorrect
> assumption. WIndows *.wim files can contain multiple streams, and the
> wim container is intelligent enough to *SHARE* files between them. so
> removing the other 3 streams may only give you a small decrease in
> overall wim file size, typically less than 10MB. Probably not what you
> are looking for.